# secret must be set using command-line option or configuration file

Tags: parallel-python

I have written a code for parallel programming in python.I am using pp module for this.

job_server = pp.Server(ncpus, ppservers=ppservers)

where ncpus=8 which is no. of core in my system.

python version:2.6.5.

pp version:1.6.2.

But I am facing an error as follows,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/a3rmt/LIVE_ECG/file_video.py", line 613, in <module>
  MakeImagesThread(array_file)
File "/home/a3rmt/LIVE_ECG/file_video.py", line 502, in MakeImagesThread
  job_server = pp.Server(ncpus, ppservers=ppservers)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/pp.py", line 366, in __init__
  raise ValueError("secret must be set using command-line option or configuration file")
ValueError: secret must be set using command-line option or configuration file
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [manual explains](http://www.parallelpython.com/content/view/15/30/#SECURITY) you need to provide a secret key to keep the communications between the process secure.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
job_server = pp.Server(ncpus, ppservers=ppservers, secret="password")
```

Where 'password' is your secret, used when setting the ppserver, eg.

> ppserver -s password

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a problem with older versions of pp (version < 1.6.4) . I reinstalled pp version 1.6.4 manually and the issue was gone . the link for download is : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pp